# C++ template converting string to number

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template function:

```
  template <typename N>
  inline N findInText(std::string line, std::string keyword)
  {
    keyword += " ";
    int a_pos = line.find(keyword);
    if (a_pos != std::string::npos)
    {
      std::string actual = line.substr(a_pos,line.length());
      N x;
      std::istringstream (actual) >> x;
      return x;
    }
    else return -1; // Note numbers read from line must be always < 1 and > 0
  }
```

It seems like the line:

```
 std::istringstream (actual) >> x;
```

Doesn't work.
However the same function not templated:

```
    int a_pos = line.find("alpha ");
    if (a_pos != std::string::npos)
    {
      std::string actual = line.substr(a_pos,line.length());
      int x;
      std::istringstream (actual) >> x;
      int alpha = x;
    }
```

Works just fine.
Is it an issue with std::istringstream and templates ???

I am looking for a way to read configuration files and load parameters which can be int or real.

EDIT solution:

```
template <typename N>
  inline N findInText(std::string line, std::string keyword)
  {
    keyword += " ";
    int a_pos = line.find(keyword);
    int len = keyword.length();
    if (a_pos != std::string::npos)
    {
      std::string actual = line.substr(len,line.length());
      N x;
      std::istringstream (actual) >> x ;
      return x;
    }
    else return -1;
  }
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? What is `N`? Do you get a compilation error?

Comment: no compilation errors. I call the function as this: alpha = var::findInText<float>(line,"alpha");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the string you're reading in can't be converted to a number, so you're returning uninitialized garbage.  That's happening because you're reading in the wrong string -- if `line` is `foo bar 345` and `keyword` is `bar`, then `actual` gets set to `bar 345`, which doesn't convert to an integer.  You instead want to convert `345`.

You should rewrite your code like this:

```
    std::string actual = line.substr(a_pos + keyword.length());
    N x;
    if (std::istringstream (actual) >> x)
        return x;
    else
        return -1;
```

That way, you convert the proper substring, and you also properly handle the case when that can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: Line contains three things a keyword a space and a number, and I'm only interested in the number.

Comment: Actually i needed: int len = keyword.length();  std::string actual = line.substr(len,line.length());
But thank you for pointing this out !